# Magic Mouse middle click in Windows 8 with Boot Camp

Tags: bootcamp, mouse, windows

I've seen this asked around the web quite a bit, but nothing recent, so I'm hoping someone has an answer.

I've got Windows 8 loaded with Boot Camp, and a Magic Mouse. The mouse left and right click works fine, but I'm hoping to have middle-click functionality. It's 3-finger click in OSX (I don't remember if that was with MagicPrefs or built in), but I'm trying to do the same in Windows.

I've seen something where you can do a middle-click by doing Ctrl-Click or something like that, but I'm looking for a regular mouse solution.

Thanks

Comment: Middle-click isn't built-in, just to confirm. http://cl.ly/image/0B2Z201z1A2k This is definitely MagicPrefs (it's all over http://magicprefs.com)